Egorov's Set for $f_{n}(x) = \frac{n\sin(x)}{1+n^{2}\sin(x)}$
I'm reading a book for Measure Thoery (Measure Theory, Grabnisnky), and I don't understand how to find the Egorov's set for $$f_{n}(x)= \frac{n\sin{x}}{1+n^{2}\sin(x)}, \quad x\in X=[0,\pi]\text{ and }\sigma=\mathbb{B}_{X} \text{ with } \mu \text{ as Lebesgue measure} $$
Where $\sigma$ is the Borel's $\sigma$-algebra in the interval $[0,\pi]$.
My first thinking was analysing the $f_{n}$. Well, if $x\in\partial X$ then $\sin{x}$ will be zero. Now taking $x\in (X-\partial X)$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$, this part $(1+n^{2}\sin{x})$ will grow up much faster than $n\sin{x}$ and therefore $f_{n\rightarrow\infty} \Longrightarrow 0, \forall x\in X$.
After this, what I should to do? I don't understand the theorem in first place, Reading the theorem, it recalls in find a epsilon, but I doesn't have any idea how to obtain that.
Everything is welcome, kind a intuitive way to understand the theorem, how to solve a similar example, thank you all!
